# Filling Data using Angular js filter method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js,

I have the following code which binds data to the div,

```
app.filter("myfilter", function () {
return function (data, catName) {
    if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(catName)) {

        var rs = [];
        var key = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var currdata = data[i][catName];

            if (angular.isUndefined(key[currdata])) {
                key[currdata] = true;
                rs.push(currdata);
            }
        }
        return rs;
    }
    else
        return data;

}
})
```

---

But when i came across the code above i found a line "key[currdata] = true;" 
what's this piece of code does?

when i comment this particular line data binding not happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simply checking that no duplicate key is pushed into `rs`

Answer (score 2):

This line is just like a mark in order that in the next iteration the condition "angular.isUndefined..." is false and, in that way, it prevents push duplicated values into rs array.

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!